# The generalisation of the expression of partial correlation coefficient

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, econometrics, partial-correlation

I hope you're doing well.

How do we use this expression of generalised partial correlation coefficient? [image]

I struggle with putting it into work in practical examples of multiple regression models.

We have the following model : y = B1+ B2x2 + B3x3 + B4x4 + B5x5 + mu

Say we want to find the expression of r14.32, the 2nd order partial correlation coefficient between y (1 stands for y here) and the exogenous variable x4, while taking out x3 and x2 effects' on y. How can I express it? How about, r15.234, the third order PCC? Or r14.5, the first order PCC.

Comment: This site has $\LaTeX$ markup for equation, please use it. See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.